# Listing all backend packages used for a specific project

Tags: node.js, express, backend, restify

I am new to backend. Currently I am using Node js + Restify + Mongo at my backend. How could I get a list of all packages used in backend for a specific project.

Comment: If allyou need is a simple list then try `npm ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check)

Install the package globally

```
npm install -g npm-check
```

Then run

```
npm-check
```

[image]